# Traefik doesn't modify location header in case of backend redirect

Tags: apache, https, traefik

I'm using Traefik to implement a reverse proxy an Apache docker container with Letsencrypt. Everything works well, except when the backend returns a 301/302 Redirect for some resources.
For example:

```
curl https://example.com/js/conf.js
> GET /js/conf.js HTTP/2
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
>

< HTTP/2 302
< cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 16:50:05 GMT
< expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< location: http://example.com/it/js/conf.js
< server: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2l
< content-length: 224
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://example.com/it/js/conf.js">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

I expect traefik to set the location header to `https://example.com/it/js/conf.js` instead.

This is the config I'm using:

```
debug = true

logLevel = "info"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

#[accessLog]

[api]
  dashboard = true

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
exposedByDefault = false

[acme]
email = "test@example.com"
storage = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true

[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

I'm running the container with the following labels:

```
--label traefik.enable=true --label traefik.website.frontend.rule=Host:example.com --label traefik.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a somewhat similar issue with traefik and gunicorn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55749349/https-request-redirected-to-http). In my case I had to pass the `X-FORWARDED_PROTO` header to let the webserver know that the initial connection was done over HTTPS. That might be why your Apache is redirecting to HTTP.