# HTTPS request redirected to HTTP

Tags: kubernetes, gunicorn, traefik, traefik-ingress

I am running Gunicorn behind a traefik ingress. HTTP is redirected to HTTPS by traefik, but for some reason gunicorn replies with a 301 pointing to HTTP. I have tried pretty much all the options I know off and didn't find any solution. I thought it might be related to something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/41488430/3719845.

Here are the annotations I use on my ingress:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: http,https
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/protocol: http
ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
traefik.frontend.rule.type: PathPrefix
ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-request-headers: 'x-forwarded-proto:https||x-forwarded-ssl:on||x-forwarded-protocol:ssl'
```

I wasn't sure that the `x-forwarded` headers were set automatically by traefik  so I hardcoded them.

On the gunicorn side, I use:

```
    command:
      - '/usr/local/bin/gunicorn'
    args:
      - '-b'
      - '0.0.0.0:8080'
      - '--log-level'
      - 'debug'
      - '--access-logfile'
      - '-'
      - '--error-logfile'
      - '-'
      - '--forwarded-allow-ips'
      - '0.0.0.0'
      - '--proxy-allow-from'
      - '0.0.0.0'
      - '--proxy-protocol'
      - 'myapp'
```

Same thing here I have been playing with the options but nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for your headers:

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-proxy-headers: "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
```

(This is a config used for aws elb.  I don't know your specific configuration leading up to it)

From there, you may have a gunicorn issue not respecting the X-Forwarded-Proto header and would want to check their docs.

Comment: This worked with the addition of `--forwarded-allow-ips *` on gunicorn.